# Insert function for every binary tree

Tags: c, function, binary-tree

If i have for example 2 binary trees:

```
typedef struct node {
    int key;
    struct node *left, *right;
} node;

node* root1
node* root2
```

I've tried  this function to insert nodes:

```
void insert(node* root, int key) {
    node *p, *q;
    p = (node*) calloc(1,sizeof(node);
    p->key = key;
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = p;
        return;
    }
    q = root;
    for (;;) {
        if (key < q->key) {
            if (q->left == 0) {
                q->left = p;
                return;
            } else q = q->left;
        } else if (key > q->key) {
            if (q->right == 0) {
                q->right = p;
                return;
            } else q = q->right;
        } else {
            free(p);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

but after call `insert(root1,10)` the tree `root1` remains untouched. I suppose it happens because `root` variable inside function is changed locally.

**How i should implement the function that will receive as argument the tree in which i want to insert nodes?**

Comment: Right, to have a change the pointer itself reflected on the outside you'll need to pass it in as a double-pointer (`**`).

Comment: Compile your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program. Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and the documentation of your compiler and debugger. Be aware that **StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework website**

Comment: Read also about [read-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)s and study for inspiration the source code of [Glib](https://blog.gtk.org/category/glib/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always return a pointer to the root, like this

```
node* insert(node* root, int key) {
    node *p, *q;
    p = (node*) calloc(1,sizeof(node));
    p->key = key;
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = p;
        return root;
    }
    q = root;
    for (;;) {
        if (key < q->key) {
            if (q->left == 0) {
                q->left = p;
                return root;
            } else q = q->left;
        } else if (key > q->key) {
            if (q->right == 0) {
                q->right = p;
                return root;
            } else q = q->right;
        } else {
            free(p);
            return root;
        }
    }
}
```

And you create your tree like -

```
node* root1 = NULL;
root1 = insert(root1,3)
```